# Add a highscore to a simple maths game

Tags: java

I am making a simple maths game, with 20 addition, subtraction and multiplication questions. I am trying to add a highscore functionality that appears at the end with the score that shows the user if they have beaten the highscore, and if they havent what the highscore currently is.

Below is the code i have so far for the game.

```
package au.edu.usc.mathgame;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A simple console-based maths quiz for primary school children.
 *
 *
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int score = 0;

    // now ask some random addition questions.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int a = rand.nextInt(20);
        int b = rand.nextInt(20);
        int questionType = rand.nextInt(3);
        Question q = new Question(a, b, questionType);
        q.showQuestion();


     // Code to print test results
        int response = input.nextInt();
        boolean result = q.checkAnswer(response);
        if (result) {
            score = score + 1;
        }

    }
    System.out.printf("Your Total Score is %2d ",score);
}
}
```

---

```
package au.edu.usc.mathgame;

import java.util.Random;

public class Question {
private int value1;
private int value2;
private int answer;
private int questionType;
private String operator;

public Question(int a, int b, int questionType) {
    value1 = a;
    value2 = b;

    Random rand = new Random();


    // Sets the operator based on the question type and calculates the answer

    if (questionType == 0) {
        operator = "+";
        answer = a + b;
    }
    else if (questionType == 1) {
        operator = "-";
        answer = a - b;
    }
    else if (questionType == 2) {
        operator = "*";
        answer = a * b;
    }

}

/**
 * Selects operator and prints question.
 *
 *
*/
public void showQuestion() {

    System.out.printf("What is %2d %s %2d? ", value1, operator, value2);
}

// checks and prints answers

public boolean checkAnswer(int response) {
    if (response == answer) {
        System.out.printf("  Yes!\n");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.printf("  No, the answer is %d.\n", answer);
        return false;
    }

}
```

}
This is a very simple game and i just want to add a highscore functionality

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem may lie in part that half the code is hidden by comment...

Comment: You need a member variable that holds the last known highest score. When a game finishes, compare the current with the last highest. If the current is greater, replace the last highest with the current.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a text file which contains the high score. Whenever your game is finished you should read that file and compare it with the current player score. If its less than the high score, Display the high score on screen else replace the value inside the file with the current player score.

For how to read and write the file in java, you can reference the below link:

[Java - Files and I/O](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm)